# PHP apostophe not being escaped. Character encoding?

Tags: php

I have a string that has an apostrophe character that can't be escaped or searched for.

Essentially I have a string that is being pulled from a 3rd party service. It is encoded as ISO-8859-1 and when it comes in, I can't escape a particular character. A sample string is below

> We’re proud to offer some exciting products that come with a full
>   manufacturer's warranty

In this case, using mysql_real_escape_string won't escape the first apostrophe, but it will escape the others. No matter what I do, I can't seem to escape the string or replace it with a normal apostrophe.

Here is what I use to acquire the file.

```
$opts = array(
          'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" 
            )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts); 
        $html = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

If I try an convert the string to UTF-8 using mb_convert_encoding(), it doesn't alter it in any way. I tried to simply replace the string using str_ireplace() on the ISO-8859-1 string and mb_ereg_replace on the UTF-8 string. Nothing has any effect.

Comment: The third character in your text isn't a straight apostrophe, so it doesn't need to be escaped. Don't worry. (But do have your eyesight checked or change your font ;-) .)

Comment: It's a "smart quote", `&lsquo;`. It *MAY* get converted to a regular quote (`'`) if you do any character set translation, so could potentially cause trouble down the road and cause an injection problem.

Comment: Hmm, an apostrophe which isn't an apostrophe doesn't need to be escaped as it isn't an apostrophe, isn't it?

Comment: What happens if you escape the string using `mysql_real_escape_string` and then insert it into the database? After you have escaped the string, it should be safe to insert it (otherwise you just found a bug...).

Comment: I understand that the character is not a straight apostrophe, but it still causes the INSERT into the MySQL to fail at that point which means I do need to worry about it. If I try to run htmlentities() on the string, it won't convert it to the equivalent entity. Conversion to other character sets either ignore it, or remove it altogether.

Comment: It appears to be an issue with the mysql_query() function itself. It cuts off the query at that character. DB, DB connection, and string are all UTF-8. If I copy and paste it into a mysql application, it runs properly, no issues.

Answer (score 2):

The first apostrophe is actually the character RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2019, `’`) and not U+0027 (`'`). And that is not escaped by `mysql_real_escape_string`.

But besides that, U+2019 is not contained in the [ISO 8859-1 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and hence cannot be encoded with ISO 8859-1.

Comment: right single quotation mark (’) is actually the “typographically correct” apostrophe. »'« is just a substitution character in the ascii/ansi space – it also replaces open quotation mark, closing quotation mark and apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

str_ireplace() is not safe on UTF-8 strings. A great deal of [info on UTF-8 is available at this link](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8).

If you really want to see it treated as a regular apostrophe, [str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace) will work fine (as noted in the UTF-8 info page referenced):

```
<?php
    
   $str = "We’re proud to offer some exciting products that come with a full manufacturer's warranty";
   print mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace('’', "'", $str));

?>
```